# Stored procedure :The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to a nullable 'System.Single' type is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, casting

I run this function :

```
public List<ViewDomainClass.Support.Report.ViewReportShopFabrication> ShowReport(int Id)
{
    List<ViewDomainClass.Support.Report.ViewReportShopFabrication> lst = new List<ViewDomainClass.Support.Report.ViewReportShopFabrication>();

    lst = _ctx.Database.SqlQuery<ViewDomainClass.Support.Report.ViewReportShopFabrication>("EXEC SPViewShopFabricationReportDetail @ReportDetailId ="+Id).ToList();
    return lst;
}
```

And I get this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to a nullable 'System.Single' type is not valid.

I know that the problem is casting. But my database columns are about 40 columns. So I want to find the exactly cast column? Is it possible to find which column returns the error?

Comment: is there an inner exception or sth. in the stacktrace that might help us?

Comment: Please check for the inner exception by attaching a debugger

Comment: @nozzleman you know ,my question just is ,this error occurs many times for me .so i have to search from all columns in my view to find the problem ,i just want to know  is there any way to find the columns that caused the error

Comment: @EhsanAkbar well, if the Exception doesn't contain enything which helps, say a column or properyname (which I don't know because I can not reproduce the problem), you might just end up having to search by the types. As stated in my answer, the message hints you the colum- and model-types which helps to shrink down canditates. However, you should try and have the correct types applied in the first place which isn't that hard, escpecially using recources like the link I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provided very little details, I can't provide a succinct answer. All I can do is to point out that the problem seems to be a sort of "text"-column which maps to one of your models properties of the Type `System.Single` (maybe just a typo when trying to write `string`?).

This might help you to shrink down possible candidates.

Once found, you just have to map the column to the appropriate .NET-Type.

You can find SQL Server - .NET Type-Equivalents on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)